# Empty array after properly filled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I receive an empty value for `NSMutableArray` and already checked that was filled properly.

What I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayQuattro;
```

.m file

```
@synthesize arrayQuattro;

//when set
 self.arrayQuattro = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [self.arrayQuattro addObjectsFromArray:llistaArxius]; 

//and when is called and receive empty value,

for (int i; i < self.arrayQuattro.count; i++){
...
```

Comment: which empty value? Where? Provide a bit more information please. Sorry, I didn't finish the mind-reading course yet

Comment: Are you sure you have some objects in your llistaArxius array ?

Comment: You really should initialise i to 0, ie: `for (int i = 0; i < self.arrayQuattro.count; i++){...`

Comment: Place `NSLog (@"elements count in llistaArxius: %d",llistaArxius.count);` and `NSLog (@"elements count in arrayQuattro: %d",llistaArxius.count);`. Place the last
sentence before entering the loop also and tell us the results.

Comment: yes, sure, I am debugging it and array is filled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. This should pretty much work for you.

```
 `self.arrayQuattro = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:llistaArxius];`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you check your elements of llistaArxius array.Because, I have tried this code and it works fine...... :)

Answer (score 0):

just replace these two lines

```
self.arrayQuattro = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [self.arrayQuattro addObjectsFromArray:llistaArxius];
```

with this:

```
self.arrayQuattro = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:llistaArxius];
```

Try this if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that the array is empty because the for loop was not entered, it is probably because your integer `i` is not initialized.  Therefor it contains some garbage value which was likely higher than the value of `self.arrayQuattro.count`, making it appear that the array was empty (hopped over the for loop).

Should be:

```
for (int i=0; i < self.arrayQuattro.count; i++) {
...
```

Comment: No, I am saying that is empty because I am debugging it and see its value at this line.